# FFmpeg - How to scale a video then apply a watermark?

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay, scale, watermark

Im trying to scale a video so that it is always 512 wide where the height changes in proportion to the original video.
Once scaled, I then want to apply a watermark/overlay to the video, therefore the video will scale but the watermark wont.

I am able to achieve each of these separately using the following filters:

**Scale**

```
-vf "scale=512:-1"
```

**Watermark**

```
-vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]"
```

They work successfully on their own.

However when trying to combine the two, Im having a bit of trouble.

Having both as parameters of course does not work as one will override the other.

Ive tried:

```
-vf "scale=512:-1,movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]"
```

my thinking was that the scale would be applied first then the watermark but all I get is an error

> Too many inputs specified for the "movie" filter.
>
> Error opening filters!

Then changing the , to a ; resulted in:

> Simple filtergraph 'scale=512:-1;
> movie=watermark.png
> [watermark]; [in][watermark]
> overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]' does not have
> exactly one input and output.
>
> Error opening filters!

I presume I need to do something more with filterchains but Im struggling to figure it out.

Any ideas anyone?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not programming-related - try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: I think it is better first scale the watermark image and after applying it in the scale video. You can try to do a pipe between the two process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thank you to both @DiJuMx and @LordNeckbeard, you both got me closer to my solution. Ive not tried the filter_complex option yet but it certainly looks simpler.

The solution I found to work is:

```
-vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in]scale=512:trunc(ow/a/2)*2 [scale]; [scale][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]"
```

Note that Ive replaced the -1 in the scale as that had the potential to cause an uneven number of pixels in the height of the video when scaling which would then cause encoding errors.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `-filter_complex` option with the scale and overlay filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=512:-1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" output
```

- See [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter documentation for more info.
- No need for the [movie](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie) source filter as in the other examples.
- You can add `-c:a copy` if you want to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the original audio instead of re-encoding it. This is useful if your input and output container formats are the same.
- The example will place the logo in the center. For other placement options:

  - Upper left with 10 px padding: `overlay=10:10`
  - Upper right with 10 px padding: `overlay=W-w-10:10`
  - Lower right with 10 px padding: `overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10`
  - Lower left with 10 px padding: `overlay=H-h-10:10`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this might work:

```
-vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in] scale=512:-1,[watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]"
```

You apply the scale filter to the input "[in]".

Unfortunately I don't have much experience with the filters on ffmpeg so I can't help further. Sorry