# Add a scaled watermark to a video using ffmpeg

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay, scale, watermark

Lie a few others I'm trying to watermark a video with an image (see [FFmpeg - How to scale a video then apply a watermark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934420/ffmpeg-how-to-scale-a-video-then-apply-a-watermark)). Oh, and I'm transcoding the format too.

The difference is I want my image to be the exact same size as the video. I need to do this as a filter chain because each video is a different size and I'm using a single watermark image. Furthermore, the server it has to run on has an older version of ffmpeg so it doesn't recognise the `-filter_complex` option.

So far, I've gotten as far as

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_video.mov -vcodec libx264 -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [watermark] scale=main_w:main_h [scaled_watermark]; [in][scaled_watermark] overlay=0:0 [out]" output_video.m4v
```

The problem is that the `main_w` and `main_h` constants only seem to be recognised in the overlay filter graph and not in the scale filter graph.

So how do I find out the width and height of `input_video.mov` so that I can scale the watermark correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use a newer `ffmpeg` on that server?

Comment: That's not an option I have with this server.