# How to rescale input video then scale and overlay watermark with Ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to rescale input video then scale and overlay watermark with Ffmpeg?

I've tried both these commands and they don't work.  Can someone help me with the process?

```
-vf \"movie={watermarkPath}[watermark]; [in] scale=720:-1 [scale]; [scale] [watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 \"
-filter_complex \"[0:v]scale={wm.Item3}:{wm.Item4}[bg];[bg][1:v]movie='{watermarkPath}'[wm];[wm][0] scale2ref={wm.Item1}:{wm.Item2}[wm] [v];[wm] setsar=1[logo];[v] [logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10\"
```

Comment: Show the actual, unscripted command (the second one) and the complete console output. Showing actual errors is always more informative than just saying it "doesn't work".

Comment: ffmpeg -i Wildlife_1897.wmv -i videoendocrinology_watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale = 512:-1[bg];[1:0] scale2ref=213:42 ; [bg] [1:v] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" output.mp4

Comment: this command results in this error:

Comment: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_scale2ref_1

Comment: got it:  ffmpeg -i Wildlife_1897.wmv -i videoendocrinology_watermark.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=212:42[wm]; [0]scale = 720:404[scaledv];[scaledv][wm] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10" output.mp4

Comment: You should always [edit] your question to add more info instead of trying to cram it into comments, and always show the **complete** console output, not just excerpts.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934420/ffmpeg-how-to-scale-a-video-then-apply-a-watermark), anyway for your refernce, you can use below command for scale and overlay

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=512:-1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" output
```